# find count of specific digits in a large factorial

Tags: c, optimization, count, factorial

I need to calculate count of a specific digit (between 0 & 9) in a large factorial of number

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int x;
    int n , count = 0;
    scanf("%llu %d", &x , &n);
    int i = x - 1;
    while(i > 1)
    {
        x *= i;
        i--;
    }
    while (x>0)
    {
        if(x%10 == n) count++;
        x /= 10;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

This works well for small numbers
**input :**
`7 0`

**output :**
`2`

**description :** 7! = 5040 which has two zeros

But takes a long time for large numbers
**input :**
`50 2`

**output :**
`overflow and time limit!`

Is there any idea to optimize this program in terms of time?
for example a mathmatic way for calculate number of digits without calculate factorial

Comment: Note that you can't compute 50! using `unsigned long long`. The most is 20! but 21! overflows. I don't understand why you are getting a *time limit* for 50! though.

Comment: You will need to move to an extended-precision format if you want to calculate `50!`.  The easiest thing would be to use a language like Python that has builtin bignum support.  If you want to use C, you'll need to find an extended-precision integer package (or write one yourself).

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) will approximate the *total* number of digits, which might be handy if you are making your own big factorial function.

Comment: @WeatherVane *I don't understand why you are getting a time limit for 50! though* Likely CPU time is limited with something like `ulimit -t ...`

Comment: @AndrewHenle but the code only needs 49 multiplications and 18 divisions! It's pretty tough measuring that short a time interval.

Comment: @WeatherVane A shared server with draconian `cgroup` CPU limits, then?  ***Someone*** doesn't want processes sucking up CPU time from that message, and there are much finer accounting (and limiting) methods available than `ulimit`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle perhaps, but I would bet that `printf()` and its OS call takes more time than the arithmetic. I wondered if that was from some other code attempt.

Comment: Regarding the mathematical question, there is a trick to calculate the number of trailing zeros, but that doesn't give you the total number of zeros or the total number of some other digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found my answer, which could be helpful for others.

The Idea is using [big numbers multiplication](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-numbers-represented-as-strings/):

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n , p;
    scanf("%d %d" , &n , &p);
    int digits[1000] = {1};
    for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0 ; k < 1000 ; k++) digits[k] *= i;
        for(int k = 0 ; k < 1000 ; k++) if(digits[k] > 9)
            {
                digits[k+1] += digits[k]/10;
                digits[k] %= 10;
            }
    }
    int a , count = 0;
    for(a = 999 ; !digits[a] ; a--);
    a++;
    for (int j = 0;j<a;j++) if(digits[j] == p) count++;
    printf("%d" , count);
}
```